# What is the relationship between kerning in TeX and kerning in a font?

Tags: kerning

Fonts in TTF or OTF often have kerning tables which can be accessed by a typesetting program that is using the font.

What is the relationship between these font-specific kerning tables and automatic kerning that may be performed by TeX?

For example, a font might recommend a particular kerning between "V" and "A", but in different words the kerning from the font table might be more or less aesthetic. For example, the word "AVAIL" would be closely kerned by a traditional typesetter, but the word "AVILA" would be more spaced out to balance the gap created by the "LA" later in the word. Obviously such kerning requires whole-word awarness which is not possible in a kerning table.

So, how does TeX deal with this? Does it just ignore the font's kerning table and apply its own ideas of proper kerning (which hopefully are whole-word-aware)? Or does it use the kerning table and only intervene if no kerning table is available? I guess there is a third possibility that it could start with the value in the kerning table and either modify it, or examine the value and make an intelligent judgement whether it should be used or not.

Comment: tex uses the kerning table from the fonts.

Comment: In addition to the automatic kerning that derives from font kerning tables, there is the `\kern{}` command that allows one-off insertion/removal of unbreakable space at the user's direction.